# Moving the third partition might prevent the boot of os

Tags: boot, partition, embedded, gparted

I have a wokring image file for an ARM embedded Linux system.
The rootfs partition is way too big and I want to shrink it.

Initial scenario:

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 7,22 GiB, 7744782336 bytes, 15126528 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device       Boot    Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/loop0p1 *        2048   206847   204800  100M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/loop0p2        206848 12789759 12582912    1G 83 Linux
/dev/loop0p3      12789760 12810239    20480   10M a2 unknown
```

The second partition (rootfs) is the one to be reduced.
I opened `/dev/loop0` with gparted and reduced it to 1G.
Then I tried to move the third partition (I don't know that it is nor what contains) just after the previous - otherwise it makes non sense at all!

But gparted told me that moving this partition might prevent the os to boot.
As far as I know, only the "boot" partitions (i.e. the first ones) are critical for boot itself.

Why moving the third one might prevent the boot?

Comment: Please make sure to translate "sconosciuto" and best all the other entries (Fine, Settori etc.), too - it is confusing otherwise.

Comment: Please prefix commands with `LANG=C` to get the output in English.

Comment: It is not  confusing for people that have seen `fdisk` output before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because the partition type is a2.

```
A2  Hard Processor System (HPS) ARM preloader
```

This partition type is used for bootable images of ARM-type computers.

For a normal Linux system that uses an x86, you should be able to delete this partition.

----edit----

Because this is ARM, it is the preloader image. It is a number of 64K blocks used as first stage boot loader. Whether or not you can move it, depends a bit on your board. Some boards use the partition table to find a type 42 image  partition.

The preloader is used as an intermediate step between the bootrom and the boot loader, so it runs before Linux is booted.

Comment: It's actually an ARM. I tried to delete it but it doesn't boot. So, how to move it?

Comment: Well, it seems that moving the partition does not prevent the boot.

Comment: So, for an ARM it is the preloader.